# how to unblock ip address with iptables command?

Tags: ip

I get my own ip address (maybe 123.45.6.7).

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 123.45.6.7 -j DROP
```

Now i was blocked myself,when i login server with other pc ,how to write iptables command to unblock myself?

I don't want to run the `iptables -F` .

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of `http://askubuntu.com/questions/193858/how-to-delete-or-unblock-an-ip-address-listed-in-iptables-firewall`

Answer (score 9):

If only a single rule matches the source address and action you can delete the rule by simply replacing `-I` (insert) by `-D` (delete):

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 123.45.6.7 -j DROP
```

If there are multiple rules matching you can list all the rules:

```
iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers
```

and delete the rule by its number *n*:

```
iptables -D INPUT n
```

Answer (score 2):

**allow access to an IP**

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
```

**to allow access to an IP to a specific port using iptables**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx --dport PORT -j ACCEPT
```